# XML File Retrieval wont work on IE or Chrome

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, google-chrome

Why wont the following script work on Chrome or IE? It works on Safari and FF. I am just trying to find a basic way to retrieve data from an XML file and display it through HTML. Thanks!

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "cd_catalog.xml", false);
            xmlhttp.send();
            xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

            document.write("<table border='1'>");
            var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                document.write("<tr><td>");
                document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                document.write("</td><td>");
                document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                document.write("</td></tr>");
            }
            document.write("</table>");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you executing your code on a server (like Tomcat)?

Comment: No, Im just doing this through the browser. Why would it work on Safari/FF and not Chrome/IE?

Comment: Check the Console Tab in Chrome (press F12) and check if you are getting a Cross Origin Request Error. I have faced the same issue in the past.

Comment: Thanks Harry! Looks like the xml source file has to have an http url to it and it has to be on the same server as the html file. Problem solved!